# Declaring two different methods which use the same parameters

Tags: c++

I have two methods to set the construct a parallelogram:

```
parallelogram(tiny_vec<float, 3> p1, tiny_vec<float, 3> p2, tiny_vec<float, 3> p3);
parallelogram(tiny_vec<float, 3> p1, tiny_vec<float, 3> height_vec, tiny_vec<float, 3> width_vec);
```

The first creates it out of three points and calculates the fourth.
The second takes one point and two vectors and calculates the other three points from that.
However, both, points and vectors, are stored as a 3d vector `tiny_vec<float, 3>`

Is there any convention how to handle this? 
Merge them into one method and add a `bool use_height_and_width` parameter?
Add a useless parameter to one and give it a default value?

Haven't found any answers, just the opposite question (different types, one method)

Comment: typedef the different tiny_vecs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Give the functions different names which make the meaning of the parameters clear. If they are constructors, make them instead appropriately named static member functions which return parallelogram objects.

See the [Named Constructor Idiom](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#named-ctor-idiom).

Answer (score 3):

Make points and vectors different types. This also has the benefit of helping to catch errors such as adding two points together.

Comment: But they behave exactly the same... Adding 2 points also makes sense, as you can add/substract position vectors.

Comment: @PattuX No, it doesn't make sense to add two points. If you add them coordinatewise, you're really implicitly treating one or the other as a vector.

Comment: Yes, but imo writing `tiny_vec<float, 3> pv_vec = point - tiny_vec<float, 3>(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f)` everytime before you can "add" 2 points gets ugly.
Anyway, the extent of that change would be too big now, but I'll consider it the next time. :)

Comment: @PattuX That wouldn't be a problem if `point` had the correct type in the first place :P

Comment: If I want to add two points, I can't do `point p1, p2; point p3 = p1 + p2;` if I want to catch adding two points, but I have to convert either `p1` or `p2` to a vector first. Anyway, I'll go with tag dispatching for now as the easiest and fastest solution ^^

Answer (score 2):

Tag dispatching would help discriminating the right function:

```
struct from_vecs {};

parallelogram(tiny_vec<float, 3> p1, tiny_vec<float, 3> p2, tiny_vec<float, 3> p3);
parallelogram(from_vecs, tiny_vec<float, 3> p1, tiny_vec<float, 3> height_vec, tiny_vec<float, 3> width_vec);
```

Or even:

```
struct from_points {};
struct from_vecs {};

parallelogram(from_points, tiny_vec<float, 3> p1, tiny_vec<float, 3> p2, tiny_vec<float, 3> p3);
parallelogram(from_vecs, tiny_vec<float, 3> p1, tiny_vec<float, 3> height_vec, tiny_vec<float, 3> width_vec);
```

---

Otherwise, use a template function:

```
enum class Tag { Points, Vecs };

template<Tag>
parallelogram(tiny_vec<float, 3>, tiny_vec<float, 3>, tiny_vec<float, 3>);
```

Thus fully specialize it:

```
template<>
parallelogram<Points>(tiny_vec<float, 3>, tiny_vec<float, 3>, tiny_vec<float, 3>) { }

template<>
parallelogram<Vecs>(tiny_vec<float, 3>, tiny_vec<float, 3>, tiny_vec<float, 3>) { }
```

You can later invoke it as:

```
parallelogram<Vecs>(/* ... params ...*/);
```

Comment: This seems like a very strange thing to do. If you're going to have to type `parallelogram(from_vec, ...`, why not just rename the function `parallelogram_from_vec`?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley ... Change name to the functions? I agree and that's why I upvoted your answer, but I guess that's not what the OP wants to do. So, here is an alternative. :-)

Answer (score 0):

A real life scenerio that I've seen was to use enum (or #define etc.) and dispatch function at runtime. Something like this:

```
enum f_tybe
{ 
    f1,
    f2,
    f3
}

int f(f_type ft, int a, int b)
{
    switch(ft)
    {
    case f1:
       return f1imp(a, b);
    break;
    case f2:
       return f2imp(a, b);
    break;
    case f3:
       return f3imp(a, b);
    break;
}
```

Or to add extra parameter like this:

```
int f(int a, int b)
int f(int a, int b, void* c)
```

I personally saw both cases in some big frameworks (winapi, directx, etc.).

But the best idea is to give functions different names.